# How to let the tar not be None?

Tags: python, transformer-model, tensorflow2

> *I don't know why does the last line show that the tar is 0 and its shape is (None, None).
>
> However, the second line in the end shows that the tar's shape is (64, 27).
>
> How to let the tar not be None?*

```
train_step_signature = [
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64),
    ]

@tf.function(input_signature=train_step_signature)
def train_step(inp, tar):
    print(tar)
    
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    start = time.time()
  
    train_loss.reset_states()
    train_accuracy.reset_states()

    # inp -> portuguese, tar -> english
    for (batch, (inp, tar)) in enumerate(train_dataset):

        print(tar)
        train_step(inp, tar)
        break
```

> ***The ouput is:***

```
tf.Tensor(  
[[1942  777 1186 ...    0    0    0]  
 [1942   22  164 ...    0    0    0]  
 [1942    1  410 ...    0    0    0]  
 ...   
 [1942  824  895 ...    0    0    0]  
 [1942  393  356 ...    0    0    0]  
 [1942 1518 1209 ...    0    0    0]], shape=(64, 27), dtype=int64)  
 Tensor("tar:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=int64)
```

> *When adding two lines in ninth line, I get the wrong sentences:
>
> **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'**
>
> How to solve this problem?*

```
train_step_signature = [
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int64),
    ]

@tf.function(input_signature=train_step_signature)
def train_step(inp, tar):
    print(tar)
    img=tf.pad(tar[:, 0:2], [[0, 0], [0, tar.shape[1]-2]])
    print(img）

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    start = time.time()
  
    train_loss.reset_states()
    train_accuracy.reset_states()

    # inp -> portuguese, tar -> english
    for (batch, (inp, tar)) in enumerate(train_dataset):

        print(tar)
        train_step(inp, tar)
        break
```

Comment: Replace `tar.shape[1]` with `tf.shape(tar)[1]` and see if the error is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's really helpful for me.